# How do you make a function add 1 to itself every time it's called?

Tags: c++

The first time the function is called it returns 1. Every other time it's called it returns 1+the number returned the last time it was called.

```
int counter()
{
   return counter()++;
}
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a [static variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable):

```
int counter()
{
   static int count = 0;   // initialized only once across all calls
   return ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `static`.

```
int counter()
{
   static int counter = 0;
   return ++counter;
}
```

Static (in the function body context) is just a nice keyword that makes a variable essentially global, but not semantic-wise. So you cannot use it outside of the function, but it gets initialized with all the globals (it means once near the start point) and it is stored where other global variables are.

Just for the record, since `c++` label. You could write a functor class, with a private `count` variable and overload `operator()`. Or even probably a template that would be able to wrap any function and count its calls.

Also note that in your try, you call `counter` recursively with no exit point with a fixed value. It will never finish (unless you count stack overflowing as end).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from defining a static local variable in the function as it was already shown you can define a static class member function that will increment a static data member of the same class. For example

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter
{
public:
    static int Count() { return ( ++cnt ); }
    static int Reset() { return ( cnt = 0 ); }
private:
    static int cnt;
};

int Counter::cnt = 0;

int main()
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) std::cout << Counter::Count() << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;

   std::cout << "\nResetting the counter to " << Counter::Reset() << std::endl;

   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) std::cout << Counter::Count() << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using C++11, use a `std::function` and a mutable lambda expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    function<int()> func = [&]()
    {
        static int i = 1;
        return i++;
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << func() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```